# Detect touch event on global UIWindow object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, touch, uiwindow

I have created a `UIWindow` global object for my application like

```
#define APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW ((UIWindow*)((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])).window
```

Now in one `UIViewController`, I m adding a subview with a transparent background to the `APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW`.

I want such a functionality that, when I touch on the transparant background added on the `APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW`, I want to close the subview.

How can I detect touch on `APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW`, so that on that Touch event, I can close the view with its subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now in one UIViewController, I m adding a subview with a transparent background to the APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW.

You could add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the subview with the transparent background. Then in the handler of the gesture recognizer, you would remove the view controller with its views.

Comment: Thanks that was a great help... For no reason I was searching for the detect of touch on UIWindow, thanks again.